# PHP exits with "double free or corruption" error

Tags: php, coredump

I have quite strange error when my cli script done its job (see below) and then whole interpreter get core dumped.

This happens on both ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 (daily image from official web site) and with both php 5.5.3 (from packages on 13.10) and 5.5.8 (compiled from source).

Environment is vagrant x64 box.

Can someone suggest any possible solution please, I spent already 2 days to get into problem and has no solution.

```
*** Error in `php': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000002203aa0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80996)[0x7f87ae7f5996]
php(sapi_shutdown+0x17)[0x6940f7]
php(main+0x3bf)[0x461a6f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f87ae796de5]
php[0x461c5b]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00bf0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 67085                              /usr/bin/php5
00def000-00e90000 r--p 007ef000 08:01 67085                              /usr/bin/php5
00e90000-00e9c000 rw-p 00890000 08:01 67085                              /usr/bin/php5
00e9c000-00eba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02203000-028ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f87a37ed000-7f87a37f3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2030                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f87a37f3000-7f87a39f2000 ---p 00006000 08:01 2030                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f87a39f2000-7f87a39f3000 r--p 00005000 08:01 2030                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f87a39f3000-7f87a39f4000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 2030                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f87a39f4000-7f87a3a00000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f87a3a00000-7f87a3bff000 ---p 0000c000 08:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f87a3bff000-7f87a3c00000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f87a3c00000-7f87a3c01000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f87a5f44000-7f87a5f59000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2181                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f87a5f59000-7f87a6158000 ---p 00015000 08:01 2181                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f87a6158000-7f87a6159000 r--p 00014000 08:01 2181                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f87a6159000-7f87a615a000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 2181                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f87a615a000-7f87a6240000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4028                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f87a6240000-7f87a643f000 ---p 000e6000 08:01 4028                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f87a643f000-7f87a6447000 r--p 000e5000 08:01 4028                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f87a6447000-7f87a6449000 rw-p 000ed000 08:01 4028                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f87a6449000-7f87a645e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87ae1ad000-7f87ae336000 r--p 00000000 08:01 60739                      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f87ae336000-7f87ae357000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2083                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f87ae357000-7f87ae556000 ---p 00021000 08:01 2083                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f87ae556000-7f87ae557000 r--p 00020000 08:01 2083                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f87ae557000-7f87ae558000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 2083                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f87ae558000-7f87ae56f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7f87ae56f000-7f87ae76f000 ---p 00017000 08:01 2076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7f87ae76f000-7f87ae770000 r--p 00017000 08:01 2076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7f87ae770000-7f87ae771000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 2076                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7f87ae771000-7f87ae775000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87ae775000-7f87ae932000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2089                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f87ae932000-7f87aeb32000 ---p 001bd000 08:01 2089                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f87aeb32000-7f87aeb36000 r--p 001bd000 08:01 2089                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f87aeb36000-7f87aeb38000 rw-p 001c1000 08:01 2089                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f87aeb38000-7f87aeb3d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87aeb3d000-7f87aec99000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f87aec99000-7f87aee98000 ---p 0015c000 08:01 4499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f87aee98000-7f87aeea0000 r--p 0015b000 08:01 4499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f87aeea0000-7f87aeea2000 rw-p 00163000 08:01 4499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f87aeea2000-7f87aeea3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87aeea3000-7f87aeea6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2091                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f87aeea6000-7f87af0a5000 ---p 00003000 08:01 2091                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f87af0a5000-7f87af0a6000 r--p 00002000 08:01 2091                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f87af0a6000-7f87af0a7000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 2091                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f87af0a7000-7f87af1aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2195                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f87af1aa000-7f87af3a9000 ---p 00103000 08:01 2195                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f87af3a9000-7f87af3aa000 r--p 00102000 08:01 2195                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f87af3aa000-7f87af3ab000 rw-p 00103000 08:01 2195                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f87af3ab000-7f87af3e8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2176                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f87af3e8000-7f87af5e8000 ---p 0003d000 08:01 2176                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f87af5e8000-7f87af5e9000 r--p 0003d000 08:01 2176                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f87af5e9000-7f87af5ea000 rw-p 0003e000 08:01 2176                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f87af5ea000-7f87af5f9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f87af5f9000-7f87af7f8000 ---p 0000f000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f87af7f8000-7f87af7f9000 r--p 0000e000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f87af7f9000-7f87af7fa000 rw-p 0000f000 08:01 2225                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f87af7fa000-7f87af967000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4356                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.1.so
7f87af967000-7f87afb66000 ---p 0016d000 08:01 4356                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.1.so
7f87afb66000-7f87afb6c000 r--p 0016c000 08:01 4356                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.1.so
7f87afb6c000-7f87afb6d000 rw-p 00172000 08:01 4356                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.1.so
7f87afb6d000-7f87afbc1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2056                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f87afbc1000-7f87afdc1000 ---p 00054000 08:01 2056                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f87afdc1000-7f87afdc4000 r--p 00054000 08:01 2056                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f87afdc4000-7f87afdca000 rw-p 00057000 08:01 2056                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f87afdca000-7f87afdcb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87afdcb000-7f87aff7d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2227                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f87aff7d000-7f87b017d000 ---p 001b2000 08:01 2227                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f87b017d000-7f87b0198000 r--p 001b2000 08:01 2227                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f87b0198000-7f87b01a3000 rw-p 001cd000 08:01 2227                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f87b01a3000-7f87b01a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87b01a7000-7f87b01bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2205                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7f87b01bd000-7f87b03bd000 ---p 00016000 08:01 2205                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7f87b03bd000-7f87b03be000 r--p 00016000 08:01 2205                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7f87b03be000-7f87b03bf000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 2205                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7f87b03bf000-7f87b03c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87b03c1000-7f87b03d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2049                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f87b03d9000-7f87b05d8000 ---p 00018000 08:01 2049                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f87b05d8000-7f87b05d9000 r--p 00017000 08:01 2049                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f87b05d9000-7f87b05da000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 2049                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f87b05da000-7f87b05fd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2095                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f87b07e7000-7f87b07ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87b07f0000-7f87b07f7000 r--s 00000000 08:01 4256                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f87b07f9000-7f87b07fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f87b07fc000-7f87b07fd000 r--p 00022000 08:01 2095                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f87b07fd000-7f87b07ff000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 2095                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fff641e5000-7fff64206000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff642d9000-7fff642db000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: if php crashes to the point of PHP **itself** crashing, then there's something majorly wrong. bad plugin, bad compile, bad library... something's bad.

Comment: Yeah, it's obvious, but the scripts which (potentially) cause this error is so badly written that I can't localize the problem. I have strong bad feeling about `declare` statement and `pcnt_*` functions use, but `sapi_shutdown` in backtrace is quite surprising cause (it looks like) there are no shutdown handlers set in code (just made a search trough all script sources).

Comment: upd: looks like `proctitle` extension is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been 6 years already, but yes, the original issue was due to incompatible `proctitle` extension that while been managed to compile, didn't work correctly with that php version. AFAIR, at that time it was unmaintained for a while already.